# Kivy deploying error

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having an error on the last command when trying to deploy my app on my Android Phone. I'm using kivy version 1.8.0

Can anyone please at least try to tell me what is the problem as I am new to kivy and want to develop my own apps with kivy. Below is the error message I got:

---

```
Distribution will be located at /dist/weather
The distribution /dist/weather already exist
Press a key to remove it, or Control + C to abort.
r
rm: /dist/weather: Permission denied
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "weather"
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 of the log: `The distribution /dist/weather already exists.`
This may be the reason for `Command failed`. The log also gives you the way to fix it -> remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did try to delete the folder and change the log error to 2, but still I get the same problem. I tried searching for some answers on google but still end up with nothing

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by downgrading the version of cython from 0.22 to .20 now it works like charm...